# How to display coordinates of Sphere in Java 3d

Tags: java, java-3d

I have a universe containing a lots of Sphere objects with different colors placed in different locations. What I need to do now is to find a way to display the coordinates of the center of a sphere when clicking on it with the mouse, so that the user is going to be able to retreive this data in a user-friendly way.

Is there someone who has an idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are wanting to retrieve the 3D coordinates of the Sphere.
The most obvious solution is to define your own location-storing object [ x y z].
Keep a copy of the location whenever your program is first creating a Sphere.

Are you using this pre-defined Sphere?:

com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.Sphere